# PHP Mysql Statement - multiple statements

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a PHP page that displays the results of a mysql query. each returned record is assigned a check box with the a value equal to the Row ID column.

the mysql statement in place inserts the selected rows into a new table.

I would like to add a second mysql query that updates the status of another table where the selected ID's match. the query is below:

> UPDATE despgoods_alldetails,loaddetails SET
>   despgoods_alldetails.locstatus ='LoadCreated' WHERE
>   despgoods_alldetails.despgoodsid = $val

The page PHP Code that works currently is( I am aware of some incorrect code):

```
> <?php
>     mysql_connect("localhost", "hulamin_hulamin", "Hulamin2011")or die("cannot connect");    
>     mysql_select_db("hulamin_loc")or die("cannot select DB");
>     $sql="SELECT `despgoodsid`,`crtd dept`,`customer`,`loc cust rel`,`case no`,`gross mass`,`case width`,`case length` from
> despgoods_alldetails where transporttypename= 'localpmb' and
> locstatus='unplanned' and customer <> 'customer'";
>     $result=mysql_query($sql);
>     $count=mysql_num_rows($result);   putenv("TZ=Africa/Johannesburg");   ?> <table border=0>
>     <tr>
>         <td>
>             <form name="form1" method="post">
>                 <table border=0
>                     <tr>
>                         <th>&nbsp;</th>
>                         <th width=150>Dispatch Area</th>                      
>                         <th width=150>Customer</th>  
>                       <th width=150><center>Release Number</th>
>                       <th width=130><center>Case Number</th>
>                       <th width=80><center>Weight</th> 
>                       <th width=80><center>Width</th> 
>                       <th width=80><center>Length</th> 
>                   </tr> <?php
>     while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
>                     <tr>
>                         <td><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="<?php echo $rows['despgoodsid']; ?>"></td>
>                         <td><?php echo $rows['crtd dept']; ?></td>
>                         <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
>                       <td><center><?php echo $rows['loc cust rel']; ?></td>
>                         <td><center><?php echo $rows['case no']; ?></td>
>                         <td><center><?php echo $rows['gross mass']; ?></td>
>                       <td><center><?php echo $rows['case width']; ?></td>
>                       <td><center><?php echo $rows['case length']; ?></td>
>                       
>                     </tr>                                   
> 
> <?php
>     } ?>
>                     <tr>
>                         <td colspan=3><input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next"></td>
>                     </tr>
>                     <?php
>                     
>                     
>                             
>                             $check=$_POST['check'];
>                             
>                         if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next'){  {
>                             $sql="INSERT INTO loaddetails (despgoodsid,dispatcharea,Customer, casenumber, weight, loadstatus) 
>                           SELECT `despgoodsid`,`crtd dept`,Customer,`case no`,`gross mass`,'loadplanned'
>                           FROM despgoods_alldetails WHERE `despgoodsid` = '$val'";
>                             
>                             foreach($check as $key=>$value)
>                             {
>                             $sql="INSERT INTO loaddetails (despgoodsid,dispatcharea,Customer, casenumber, weight, loadstatus)
>                           SELECT `despgoodsid`,`crtd dept`,Customer,`case no`,`gross mass`,'loadplanned'
>                           FROM despgoods_alldetails WHERE `despgoodsid` = '$value'";
>                             $final=mysql_query($sql);
>                             if($final)
>                             {
>                             echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.hulaminloc.co.za/planningplatform/planlocalpmbstep2.php\">";
>                             }                                            } 
>                                 }
>                                 }
>                    mysql_close(); ?> </table> </form> </td> </tr> </table>
```

How can I add my update statement to run in addition to the select statement for each selected row?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Ryan Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a trigger that would fire when data is saved in the secondary table; check mysql manual for triggers if you think this might be what you need

Comment: Hi, The PHP Page quoted above inserts data into a loaddetails table. I then need to alter the status of the products table for the inserted rows. I am not sure a trigger would acommodate this for only my selected rows. Thanks @mishu

Comment: considering that the table that needs to be updated is part of the query that must cause the update triggers are not the case here; so I think that you can't avoid using two separate sql queries; just run the update query you already have after the insert

Comment: note: it looks like you code would redirect after the first insert in a series

Comment: Hi @mishu, how can I run the two seperate queries though, as part of the selected rows loop?

Comment: just add the update query (that you already have) under the insert.. like this: $query = '
   UPDATE 
    despgoods_alldetails 
   SET 
    locstatus ='LoadCreated' 
   WHERE 
    despgoodsid = '.$value.'
';
$update = mysql_query($query);

Comment: but for my curiosity.. why are you even using that array if after the first insert query that succeeds you redirect the user?

Comment: thanks @Mishu. My table shows rows outputted from a mysql statement. the selected rows need to be added to the loaddetails table and the status of the goods changes on the actual products in despgoods table. is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Hi @Mishu, if I add the query below the insert statement will it be processed as part of the loop for each selected row? Is it possible for you to provide the complete syntax from when the user clicks submit?

Comment: I was just asking why you don't move the redirect outside of the foreach statement so that it would run the needed number of times.. but maybe there's something that I am missing since you don't have a problem on this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4234/discussion-between-ryan-smith-and-mishu)

Comment: yes, if you add it just under the insert query it will be processed just the number of times the first one is..

Comment: if that what you are wondering: you can also split the insert and select in two queries if you want

Answer (score 0):

I though I would post the complete working code here. Big up to @mishu for all the help and patience.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("database")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT `despgoodsid`,`crtd dept`,`customer`,`loc cust rel`,`case no`,`gross mass`,`case width`,`case length` from despgoods_alldetails where transporttypename= 'localpmb' and locstatus='unplanned' and customer <> 'customer'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    putenv("TZ=Africa/Johannesburg");

?>
<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=0
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th width=150>Dispatch Area</th>                        
                        <th width=150>Customer</th>  
                        <th width=150><center>Release Number</th>
                        <th width=130><center>Case Number</th>
                        <th width=80><center>Weight</th> 
                        <th width=80><center>Width</th> 
                        <th width=80><center>Length</th> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="<?php echo $rows['despgoodsid']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['crtd dept']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['loc cust rel']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case no']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['gross mass']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case width']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case length']; ?></td>

                    </tr>                                   

<?php
    }
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3><input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php



                            $check=$_POST['check'];

                        if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next'){
 {



$maxloadid = ' 
select 
max(loadid) +1 
from 
loaddetails 
'; 
$resultmaxloadid = mysql_query($maxloadid); // run the query 

// there was an error - output the message 
if (!$resultmaxloadid) 
{ 
echo 'there was an error in your query'; 
echo mysql_error(); 
die; 
} 

$loadid = mysql_result($resultmaxloadid, 0);

foreach($check as $key=>$value) // 
{ 
// get the details for one of the selected values 
$query = ' 
SELECT 
`despgoodsid`, 
`crtd dept`, 
`Customer`, 
`case no`, 
`gross mass` 
FROM 
despgoods_alldetails 
WHERE 
`despgoodsid` = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '" 
';

$result = mysql_query($query); // run the query 

// there was an error - output the message 
if (!$result) 
{ 
echo 'there was an error in your query'; 
echo mysql_error(); 
die; 
} 

// we got here, everything is fine 

if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) // the above query did not fetch any records, so there's a problem 
{ 
continue; // skip this record.. "continue" will ignore the rest of the foreach loop and go to the next step 
} 

$details = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

// inset the values 
$query = ' 
INSERT INTO 
loaddetails 
SET 
despgoodsid = "'.$details['despgoodsid'].'", 
dispatcharea= "'.$details['crtd dept'].'", 
Customer = "'.$details['Customer'].'", 
casenumber = "'.$details['case no'].'", 
weight = "'.$details['gross mass'].'", 
loadstatus= "loadplanned",
loadid = "'.$loadid.'" 
'; 

$result = mysql_query($query); // run the query 

// there was an error - output the message 
if (!$result) 
{ 
echo 'there was an error in your query'; 
echo mysql_error(); 
die; 
} 

// update the status 
$query = ' 
UPDATE 
despgoods_alldetails 
SET 
locstatus ="LoadCreated" 
WHERE 
despgoodsid = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '"
'; 
$result = mysql_query($query); // run the query 

// there was an error - output the message 
if (!$result) 
{ 
echo 'there was an error in your query'; 
echo mysql_error(); 
die; 
} 


} // end of foreach statement 
if($final) 
{ 
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.hulaminloc.co.za/planningplatform/index.phpx`\">"; 
}



                                }
                                }

mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks again to @Mishu and all the other contributors on the site.